# How to extract substring from one known word to another

Tags: sql, substring, qsqlquery

I am attempting to extract the string between two words (inclusive of the words.)

So as a visual example:

field content: `The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump`

stop name first token: `frog`
stop name second token: `amazing`

What I want to extract: `frog jumped over the fly in an amazing`

I tried the following code:

[what i want ] = `SUBSTRING([FIELD_CONTENT], CHARINDEX([STOP NAME FIRST TOKEN], [FIELD_CONTENT])
CHARINDEX([STOP NAME SECOND TOKEN],[FIELD_CONTENT]) - CHARINDEX([STOP NAME FIRST TOKEN], [FIELD_CONTENT]) + Len([STOP NAME SECOND TOKEN]))`

and it gives me this error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You are missing a comma before the second `CHARINDEX`

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: Really. I copied it and replaced text for the field names and it worked for me.

Comment: I've updated my answer using the strings you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma before the second `CHARINDEX`.

Try this.
**Updated with strings.**

```
Select SUBSTRING('The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump', CHARINDEX('frog', 'The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump') 
, CHARINDEX('amazing','The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump') - CHARINDEX('frog', 'The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump') + Len('amazing'))
```

**Results:**

> frog jumped over the fly in an amazing

Answer (score 0):

> Rather than making **5** function calls, you can do it in just **3** by nesting two `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`'s inside of `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT('frog',
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             SUBSTRING_INDEX('The frog jumped over the fly in an amazing jump','frog',-1),
         'amazing',1)
       ,'amazing') AS 'What I Want'
```

The first `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` generates:  `jumped over the fly in an amazing jump`
The second `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` generates: `jumped over the fly in an`
Finally `CONCAT()` re-attaches the keywords: `frog jumped over the fly in an amazing`